# "No compiler could be found" error in cmake GUI

Tags: visual-studio, cmake-gui

I am using VS 2015 and cmake 3.8. While configuring in the cmake GUI, I am getting these errors

> "No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found"
>   "No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found"

What could the reason be and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using VS 2017 or VS 2015? Bear in mind that the version number are 14 for VS 2015 and 15 for VS 2017.

Comment: At this point, CMake 3.8 is only a Release candidate. Have you tried the latest stable version (i.e. CMake 3.7.2)?

Answer (score -1):

Since you asked this question on 2017-03-07 which happened to be the release date of Visual Studio 2017 RTM and since I experienced the same issue after replacing Visual Studio 2015 with Visual Studio 2017, I will just assume that we are talking about Visual Studio 2017 here.

After a search on Google, I tried different suggestions but none of them worked. What worked for me was this:

**Install Visual Studio 2015**.

Then magically, CMake was working for Visual Studio 2017. I hope this will help you.